# Show the series diverges

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

> Show $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{\frac{x+1}{x}}}$ diverges.

I tried the integral test, but showing $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)dx $ diverges is just as difficult.

I tried comparison but I don't see a proper comparision?

Comment: Can you expand the summation and see if the next term is always greater or equal to the previous term?

Comment: Its smaller than the previous term

Answer (score 5):

We have $\frac{1}{n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}}=\frac{1}{n}*\frac{1}{n^{1/n}}$

Since $n^{1/n} \to 1$ for $ n \to \infty$, we have that $n^{1/n} \le 2$ for large $n$. Thus

$\frac{1}{n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}} \ge \frac{1}{2n}$ for large $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the AM-GM inequality, we get that for any $n\geq 1$
$$ n^{1/n} = GM\left(1,\frac{2}{1},\frac{3}{2},\ldots,\frac{n}{n-1}\right)\leq AM\left(1,\frac{2}{1},\frac{3}{2},\ldots,\frac{n}{n-1}\right)=1+\frac{H_{n-1}}{n} $$
hence:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n\cdot n^{1/n}}\geq \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n+H_{n-1}}=H_N-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_{n-1}}{n(n+H_{n-1})}\geq \log(N)-O(1). $$